# 3.3 Hyundai Santa Fe 2009 CV joint. Replaced them but now have vibration when accelerating. Is sur tack the best replacement part?

Tags: hyundai, cv-joint, santa-fe

It all went together well but now it vibrates when accelerating.  Is sur Tack a best replacement joint? Wondering if there is a better manufacturer.

Comment: Did you make sure that all the nuts were correctly tightened? Suspension, wheel etc?

Comment: yes all was tight even replace drive shaft

Comment: Thinking it was a bad part just wondering if someone thinks  there  is a better brand ,just thinking if their were out of balance their would vibrate all the time?

Comment: Never heard of them (probably because you are on a different continent..), but they could be good quality but a bad one always gets through...

Comment: I think what Solar Mike was asking is, *was everything **torqued** correctly?* It doesn't matter if everything is tight if it wasn't torqued to the proper spec. You can cause damage to the parts by not having torqued them to spec, which may in turn cause vibration.

Comment: Check Twice an were torqued right

Comment: Even got new Tires